# select columns from a pivot query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following pivot query:

```
select *
from
(
  select order_id,unit_price,quantity,sum(unit_price*quantity) 
  over (partition by order_id) as Total
 from DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS 
) tbla
pivot
(
  sum(unit_price*quantity) as unit_totals 
  for unit_price in(30,50,60,80,110,120,125,150)
) tblb
order by order_id;
```

producing following result:

```
ORDER_ID    TOTAL   30_UNIT_TOTALS  50_UNIT_TOTALS  60_UNIT_TOTALS  80_UNIT_TOTALS  110_UNIT_TOTALS 120_UNIT_TOTALS 125_UNIT_TOTALS 150_UNIT_TOTALS

1           1890    500             640             750
2           2380    60              250             180             480               220               240             500             450
3           1640    100             240             320             480 500 
4           1090    180             200             220             240 250 
5           950     150             180             320             300
6           1515    330             360             375             450
7           905 90  250             120             320             125 
8           1060    160             330             120             450
9           730     240             240             250 
10          870     250             320             300
```

I would like to change order of columns ending with the TOTAL. How can i select the columns in preferred order?
This works:select tblb.* .... but select tblb.30_UNIT_TOTALS fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote fields if they don't start with an *alphabetic character*. In addition, using quotes make the identifier case sensitive. So you have to write:

```
tblb."30_UNIT_TOTALS"
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm)

> > 4. Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.
>
> [...]
>
> > 8. Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them as uppercase. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive.